# Any good foip (T.38) clients for ubuntu?

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk, fax

At our office we have an asterisk server with T.38 set up on it. Right now we are using a fax machine with an ATA and it works good, but were hoping to go paperless. Does anyone know of any good FoIP clients available for ubuntu? Maybe even set up able as a printer so you can "print to fax"?

Comment: The article "How to send faxes directly from within LibreOffice?" explains in detail about print to fax, updated and proven to work. You should give it a try. As VoIP client I use Linphone (only available via Ubuntu snap - everything else is prone to fail). But FoiP ???? I doubt it strongly since G4 is dead and T37 and T38 are not available with all providers. FAX capability needs to be implemented as feature in VoiP because VoIP is  bullshit in terms of FAX and reliability, frequency spectres and signalling. However, the money rules - ISDN was the absolute perfection for FAX using G4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but I thought I would tell everyone what we finally ended up doing, (even though it's not very preferable)

RXFAX

Call Centric --> Asterisk server --> Uses spandsp ReceiveFAX application to save to tmp file --> Hang up

Upon hang up (exten => h,1) the dialplan would execute a shell script I made called mailfax.

Mailfax uses sendEmail to email the fax with the attachment, then deletes the tmp tiff file.

TXFAX

Script to check to see if new files in directory (sshfs share) --> Generates .call file (name of tiff file is number to dial) --> Asterisk uses spandsp SendFAX --> Call Centric

Hopefully this will be helpful to somebody, and maybe we will even see some foip applications in the future :)